# ListView in tabview doesn't update

Tags: angular, listview, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Hello I have quite strange problem with listView in TabView. I spend all day with solving this, but with no result. Because of not refreshing listView (ngZone didn't help), I have to do refresh programatically in listView. It work's, but problem is when I go to this page from another page via router then is injected via contructor previous page. 
I have login page where I do:

```
this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
```

And in home.component.ts contructor looks like:

```
constructor(ngZone: NgZone, private page: Page)
```

then I tried call:

```
var listview:ListView= <ListView> page.getViewById("listView1");
```

but it returs undefined (if login page did not exist and only home exist it works correctly). When I tried get some view from login page I get the view...

Can anybody give me advice what is wrong? I try a lot of things what i found, but nothing works... Thank you for your answer.

EDIT:
Added code snippet:
home.component.html

```
<GridLayout class="page">
    <TabView height="100%" (selectedIndexChange)="onTabChanged($event)" class="content p-20" >
        <ng-container *ngFor="let itema of objectKeys(site)" >
            <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: itema}">
                    <ListView [id]="itema" class="list-group" [items]="getData(itema)" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
                        <ng-template let-item >
                            <GridLayout class="list-group-item" rows="*" columns="auto, *">
                                <Label row="0" col="0" [text]="item.name"></Label>
                                </Image>
                            </GridLayout>
                        </ng-template>
                    </ListView>
                </GridLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-container> 

    </TabView>
</GridLayout>
```

home.components.ts part:

```
   ngOnInit(): void {
            getJSON(url).then((r: any) => {
                console.log(r);
                this.ngZone.run(() => {
                    this.site = r;
                });
                //this part added because ngZone didn't work
                var listview: ListView = <ListView>this.page.getViewById(objectKeys(this.site)[0]);
                listview.refresh();
            }, (e) => {
                //TODO handle exception
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
```

I think the problem appear because ListView are constructed dynamically (refresh didn't work in onTabChange method neither.)

Comment: Are you attempting to get assistance with your `ListView` not updating, or with accessing your `ListView` from your `HomeComponent`?

Comment: If I can get ListView update differently than listView.refresh() programaticaly than will be best, but i tried everything what I found (ngZone, etc) and listview.refresh() is only one whats work corectly... But when I add login page I cannot access to listview via page because page injected via constructor (you can see above) inject page from login not from home. I tried {frame.topmost().currentPage;} also.

Comment: You can provide some more details and code snippet?

Comment: Added. It is really because of dynamic construction of ListView... When I tried do it on static ListView, it is working.

Comment: Can you try excluding `ng-container`, see if that helps.

Comment: If I use {ng-template} not {ng-container} result is the same. But completly without {ng-template} or {ng-container} that cannot be because I need a dynamic TabView...

Comment: You are searching for id ``listView1 with `page.getViewById("listView1");
` but then there is no such ide assigned to your ListView in the HTML file at all! Remove the binding to id in the4 HTML and add `<ListView id="ilistView1"`

Comment: That's is true, but it was only wrong copy paste (I removed some unnecessary code)... I use the correct one id (ListView is found)... I have a little progress here... When data is prepared after login but not on home.component then everything is correct. But when I dynamically add another tab, data from other tabs (which are arround the new tab) dissapier and show after I click on other tabs which is not neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any issues with dynamic tabs / ng-container.

Here is a [Playground sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=yrPidv&v=2) was tested with both iOS & Android. If you still have issues on your end, please update the playground example where we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After an another day of investigate this problem I found out the core problem isn't in ListView but in TabView. I describe it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783746/nativescript-add-tab-into-tabview-dynamically-content-disappears] question. And your sample I modified [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=yrPidv&v=3).

Comment: Just try click on list item in modified sample which I link above and you will see... (Tested on android)