# Nativescript add tab into TabView dynamically - content disappears

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I asked two days ago question about [ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766717/listview-in-tabview-doesnt-update) but now I find out the core problem wasn't about listview but the problem was in TabView. On the start when It was created tabs everything looks fine but when I Tap on button which add another tab it doesn't work correctly. Tab is added (on the end) and selected index of tabs is 2 but content of previous tab (tab index 1) disappears. But when I go to last tab (index 3) and back to tab (index 1) content is there.

Here is the code snippet where you can try:

Home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page/page";
import { ListView } from "ui/list-view"

@Component({
    selector: "app-home",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    site = [{ "name": "cau 1", }, { "name": "cau 2" },
    { "name": "settings" }];

    tabSelectedIndex = 0;
    onItemTap(args) {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.site.push({ "name": "next" });
            this.tabSelectedIndex = 2;
        });
    }

    constructor(private ngZone: NgZone, private page: Page) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
    onTabChanged(args) {
        console.log("ahoj");
    }
}
```

Home.component.html

```
<ActionBar title="YOUR APP"></ActionBar>
<GridLayout class="page">
    <TabView [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex" height="100%" (selectedIndexChange)="onTabChanged($event)" class="content p-20">
        <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="site">
            <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: item.name}">

                <Label row="0" col="0" [text]="test"></Label>
                <Button text="+" class="btn btn-active tmp" (tap)="onItemTap($event)"> </Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </TabView>
</GridLayout>
```

Tested on android emulator only.

Additional question: It is possible to add new tab as first (to index 0)?

Thank you very much for your time and any answer.

EDIT: This code you can try [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=TIzFdC&v=57)

Or maybe better sample is [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=yrPidv&v=3)

Comment: Do you mean "is there a way to put something on the front of an array"? You appear to be using `.push`, which always appends to the array. Does `this.site.unshift({ "name": "next" })` do what you desire?

Comment: I know about unshift function... but sadly it doesn't put tab as a first tab in TabView. It was a first thing which i tried :) But this is only additional question... First one is more important... Btw code from question can be tried on: [nativescript-playground](https://play.nativescript.org/)

Comment: You'll have to use the "Save" function there to get a shareable URL.

Comment: Thank you... :) [Here is it](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=TIzFdC&v=57)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a nativescript issue. Answer is " adding/removing tab view items are not officially supported operations and is a known limitation for that widget." Here is [link](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6414) for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I searched A LOT how to handle this use-case. I found a solution, which I think is very nice. You need to have 2 (or more) TabViewComponents. And than by the route.navigate you navigate to the component which u want.

**Example**

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
{
    path: 'main-menu-club-logged-out', component: MainMenuClubLoggedOutComponent,
    children: [
        {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'home'},
        {path: 'find-club', component: FindClubComponent, outlet: 'findClub'},
        {path: 'check-in', component: CheckInComponent, outlet: 'checkIn'},
        {path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, outlet: 'settings'}
    ]
},
{
    path: 'main-menu-club-logged-in', component: MainMenuClubLoggedInComponent,
    children: [
        {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, outlet: 'home'},
        {path: 'club-information', component: ClubInformationComponent, outlet: 'clubInformation'},
        {path: 'check-out', component: CheckOutComponent, outlet: 'checkOut'},
        {path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, outlet: 'settings'}
    ]
},
```

*main-menu-logged-in.component.html*

```
<BottomNavigation selectedIndex="0" tabsPosition="bottom">

<TabStrip>
    <TabStripItem class="tab-view">
        <Label text="Home"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf2bd;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>
    <TabStripItem class="tab-view">
        <Label text="Club"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf3c5;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>
    <TabStripItem class="tab-view">
        <Label text="Check-Out"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf057;" class="far t-36"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>
    <TabStripItem class="tab-view">
        <Label text="Settings"></Label>
        <Image src="font://&#xf1de;" class="fas t-36"></Image>
    </TabStripItem>
</TabStrip>

<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <page-router-outlet name="home"></page-router-outlet>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <page-router-outlet name="clubInformation"></page-router-outlet>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <page-router-outlet name="checkOut"></page-router-outlet>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
<TabContentItem>
    <GridLayout>
        <page-router-outlet name="settings"></page-router-outlet>
    </GridLayout>
</TabContentItem>
```

*component.ts*

```
logoutClub() {
    this.clubService.logoutOfCurrentClub();

    this.router.navigate(['/main-menu-club-logged-in'], {
        clearHistory: true, transition: {name: 'fade'}
    });
}
```